# Since hibernate-validator 6.0.18 @SafeHtml is deprecated. I try to find an alternative

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

Since hibernate-validator 6.0.18 @SafeHtml is deprecated because of vulnerability https://in.relation.to/2019/11/20/hibernate-validator-610-6018-released/. So I made a custom XSS String fields validator. Is it correct, or I should do it in another way?

```
public class XssValidator implements ConstraintValidator<XssEscape, String> {
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String input, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(input).equals(input);
    }
}
```